# Durandal Routing not working--am I missing a configuration setting?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application, durandal

I'm trying to get a Durandal app setup and I started with a very simple configuration with just two views.

What's happening is that when I call router.navigateTo('#/welcome') or router.navigateTo('#/primaryapplicants'), the view doesn't change.  The URL in the address bar changes, however, and if I reload the page, I get the view I was trying to navigate to.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a [video demonstrating the behavior I'm experiencing](http://screencast.com/t/kSRfPjknh).  The code I referenced in the video is included below.

### main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: { "text": "durandal/amd/text" }
});

define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),
        router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
        viewLocator = require('durandal/viewLocator'),
        logger = require('services/logger');

    system.debug(true);

    app.start().then(function () {
        // route will use conventions for modules
        // assuming viewmodels/views folder structure
        router.useConvention();

        // When finding a module, replace the viewmodel string 
        // with view to find it partner view.
        // [viewmodel]s/sessions --> [view]s/sessions.html
        // Otherwise you can pass paths for modules, views, partials
        // Defaults to viewmodels/views/views. 
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        // Will assume that a URL to #/something corresponds to a viewmodels/something viewmodel.
        // http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/)
        //router.mapAuto();

        var routes = [{
            url: 'welcome',
            moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome',
            name: 'Welcome',
            visible: true
        }, {
            url: 'primaryapplicants',
            moduleId: 'viewmodels/primaryapplicants',
            name: 'Primary Applicants',
            visible: true
        }];

        router.map(routes);

        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');

        // override bad route behavior to write to 
        // console log and show error toast.
        // This method also accepts a "params" parameters, but we're not using it,
        // and to avoid JSLint warnings, we're not including it.
        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route) {
            logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
        };
    });
});
```

### shell.html

```
<div>
Shell HTML
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#/welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/primaryapplicants">Primary Applicants</a></li>
</ul>

        <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem} -->
        <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

### shell.js

```
define(['durandal/system', 'services/logger', 'durandal/plugins/router'],
    function (system, logger, router) {


        function activate() {

            // Listen for click events so we can navigate
            $('body').on('click', '#navbar a', function (event) {
                var navTo = '#/welcome';
                navTo = event.target.hash;
                logger.log('Attempting navigation to ' + navTo,
                        null,
                        system.getModuleId(shell),//ignore jslint
                        true);
                router.navigateTo(navTo);
                //alert("About to navigate to " + event.target.hash);
                //router.navigateTo(event.target.hash);
            });


            logger.log('Shell loaded',
                null,
                system.getModuleId(shell),//ignore jslint
                true);

            return router.activate('welcome');
        }

        var shell = {
            activate: activate,
            router: router
        };

        return shell;

    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it often the case, once you figure out the solution, it's really quite simple.

Apparently, in the compose binding (a custom Knockout binding provided by Durandal), you *must* have an afterCompose binding.  In other words, this:

```
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem} -->
    <!--/ko-->
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, afterCompose: router.afterCompose} -->
    <!--/ko-->
```

Without it, my navigation wouldn't work.  This is [stated clearly enough in the docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/), but I still missed it somehow:

> You must wire both the *model* and the *afterCompose* callback to the
>   router in order for everything to work properly.

Comment: Sometimes reading the docs is all that'd required. From that point on it's all about repetition to make it sink, at least for me ;-).

Comment: @Josh - I think you've misunderstood slightly - the compose binding belongs to Durandal itself (as a custom KO binding) and it doesn't actually require an afterCompose callback in normal situations, just for the shell page composition.

Comment: Ok, so it's a Durandal thing, not a native part of Knockout.  But I don't understand what you mean that the afterCompose isn't required in normal situations.  The Durandal docs say it is.  Can you explain further what you mean?